# How to call API from the MealDB

Tags: javascript, html, api, es6-modules

Hello last few days I am trying to learn call API from different site. Now I try to build a website like this. My task is call API from [The MealDB](https://www.themealdb.com/api.php) and implement a site and also show API data in card view and when I click any card it's show another view where contain all ingredients
[image: this demo]
[image: after clicking any card, this will show]
but I can't call the API from [The mealDB](https://www.themealdb.com/api.php) I wanted to implement this website by calling the mealBD API. But whenever I tried it's not work as I want. I don't know how to call that API.
My project is given below :I can't call the API
[image: this is my project]
this is my js code

```
fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=> displayFoods(data))

const displayFoods = foods =>{
const foodsDiv = document.createElement('food-items');

foods.forEach(meals=>{
    const foodDiv = document.createElement('div');

    foodDiv.className = 'meals';
    const foodInfo = `
    <h3>${meals.strMeal}</h3>

    `;
    foodDiv.innerHTML = foodInfo;
    foodsDiv.appendChild(foodDiv);
});
}
```

I used bootstrap in html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Cooking master</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<section class="container">
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cooking master</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
  target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria- 
  label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-end" 
  id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                <div class="navbar-nav">
                  <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#recipes">Recipes</a>
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#blog" tabindex="-1">Blog</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
    </header>
</section>

<section class="container input-style">
    <main class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 input-filed ">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for Meal...." aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
            <span class="input-group-text bg-color text-light" id="basic-addon2">Search</span>
          </div>
    </main>
</section>
<div id="food-items">
    
</div>









<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The result json is an object with property meals. So you cannot execute forEach on that. You need to run on foods.meals

Below is your working code.

```js
(function(){

fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=> displayFoods(data))



const displayFoods = foods =>{
const foodItemsDiv = document.getElementById('food-items');

foods.meals.forEach(meal=>{

    const foodDiv = document.createElement('div');

    foodDiv.className = 'meal';
    const foodInfo = `
    <h3>${meal.strMeal}</h3>

    `;
    foodDiv.innerHTML = foodInfo;
    foodItemsDiv.appendChild(foodDiv);
});
}

})();
```

```html
<div id="food-items">
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your browser console:

```js
fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=> console.log(data))
```

You'll see an end result like this:

```js
{
  meals: [
    { // meal 1 },
    { // meal 2 },
    { // meal 3 },
    { // meal 4 }
  ]
}
```

Inside your `displayFoods` function, you're trying to call `forEach` on this data, but [`forEach` can only operate on **arrays**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), not objects.

Instead, you need to pass the `meals` array inside the returned data to your function:

```js
fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?f=a')
.then(res=>res.json())
.then(data=> displayFoods(data.meals)) // data.meals instead of data
```